# React - state management

Tags: reactjs, react-state

I am new to React, so the idea is when button clicked to submit the email, it checks the email syntax and black listed array that contains emails that cannot be entered and if its false then Text pops out(error) , I would like warning to show after a button click however i would like warning to disappear once the state of the input changes again. Would appreciate some help

```
export default class EmailSettings extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        email: '',
        validEmail:true,
        showMessage: false
    };
}

handleEmailChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({email: e.target.value});
};

handleSubmitEmail = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const email = this.state.email;
    if(this.validateEmail(email)) {
        this.setState({validEmail: true})
        this.setState({showMessage: false});
    }else{
        this.setState({validEmail: false })
        this.setState({showMessage: true});
    }
};


  <Input style={{marginTop: '20px', width: '360px',borderColor: !this.state.validEmail ? 'red': null}}
                           placeholder={emailPlaceHolder}
                           onChange={this.handleEmailChange}/>
                    <StyledButton type="primary" onClick={this.handleSubmitEmail}>{submit}</StyledButton>
                    <div>{this.state.showMessage ? <Error>Syntax error or email is not supported</Error> : !this.state.showMessage}</div>
```

Right now whats happening is the message appears and the input border becomes red but after state changes red message or the box border is not dissapearing

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDwdZ.png)

Comment: According [react state management 2023](https://fe-tool.com/en-us/awesome-react-state-management), the most popular libraries are react-redux, xstate, and zustand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
handleEmailChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({email: e.target.value,
    validEmail:true,
    showMessage:false});
    };
```

On input, just set the non-error state, so that after submit if there's an error and the user types again the error is reset.